# Testing Kerberos locally on Windows

Tags: jboss7.x, windows-authentication, kerberos

Questions pertains to testing SSO with Windows (7) log-in credentials against a local/test KDC (Kerberos)..

Think I got the [basic picture](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.1/html-single/Security_Guide/index.html#Configure_Kerberos_or_Microsoft_Active_Directory_Desktop_SSO_for_Web_Applications) regarding authentication with log-in credentials (TGT and client-server tickets) and how JBoss has to handle negotiation against Kerberos.  However I would like to do a setup intended for development/testing.  Thought about downloading a MIT version of Kerberos and setting up the KCD.  Assuming I can use the klist/kinit tools part of the JDK 7 distribution to make my own TGT och tickets?  The log-in credentials (i.e. when I log-on to Windows) should be volatile (i.e. in memory rather than file based).

How do I get my browser(s) to pull up the correct credentials?  Is this possible from a browser?  For example with Firefox apparently SPENGO negotiating is a white list of domains but does it look at the DomainName in the TGT to grab the right one?  And how would Firefox SPENGO know to look in my local credentials that are file based rather than the volatile one?